# destructing a pointer to a dynamic 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Iv'e been trying to solve this allocation/destruction problem for a significant amount of time as part of an assignment I got from school, basically I need to allocate a 2d array pointer of a simple class i designed.

```
class RobotsWorld{
public:
    RobotsWorld(int width,int hight);
    ~RobotsWorld();
    /**
     * copy,Assign,operator=
     */
    //RobotsWorld(const RobotsWorld &);
    //void Assign(const RobotsWorld &);
    //RobotsWorld& operator=(const RobotsWorld &);


    bool addRobot(Robot & r,Point p);
    bool moveRobot(Robot & r);
    bool removeRobot(Robot & r);
    Point getPosition(Robot r);
    string toString();

    Robot* getRobotInWorld(Robot & r);

    /** validation functions **/
    bool checkOutOfBounds(int,int);
    bool isEmptySlot(int x,int y);
    bool ableToMove(Robot &);




private:
    Robot*** robots;
    Point point;
    int width,height;
};
```

this is not the full source file of the functions but these functions causes the crash\memory loss. (and yes it has to be defined as a triple pointer - ***robots)

```
RobotsWorld::RobotsWorld(int width,int height)
:width(width),height(height)
{
    robots = new Robot**;
    *robots = new Robot*[height];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++){
        robots[i] = new Robot*[width];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++)
            robots[i][j] = NULL;
    }

}

RobotsWorld::~RobotsWorld(){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++){
        delete [] robots[i];
        robots[i] = NULL;
    }
    delete [] *robots;
    delete **robots;
}
```

the robot class and the main got no allocation whats so ever.
ive been trying to search for a solution but even describing this situation proved it self difficult.

Comment: What is this: `robots = new Robot**;`???  Why not `Robot robots[] = new robot[MAX_ROBOTS];`?  Or, even better, why not `Vector<Robot> robots = new Vector<Robot>();`?

Comment: You need 3 sizes to allocate memory for a 3d array. You only have 2 (int width,int height). It looks like you only need a 2d array.

Comment: The `std::vector` class can be nested, e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<Robot>>`. Using `std::vector` will make your life **so** much easier.

Comment: If you have access to TR1/C++11, you could use smart pointers in addition to vectors. That would make things easier.

Comment: You can also use `template<int WIDTH, int HEIGHT> class RobotsWorld { Robot robots[WIDTH][HEIGHT]; };` and you do not have to handles `new`/`delete` operators ;-) However you have to implement some `operator` to handle `RobotsWorld<3,4> rw34; RobotsWorld<5,6> rw56 = rw34;`

Answer (score 4):

You need two nested loops to delete a 2D array of pointers - to delete individual robots, and to delete rows of robots:

```
RobotsWorld::~RobotsWorld(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++) {
            delete robots[i][j]; // Delete each individual robot
        }
        delete[] robots[i]; // Delete the row of robots
    }
    // Finally delete the 2D array itself
    delete[] robots;
}
```

Although it is normally a good idea to set a pointer to `NULL` after deletion, doing so in the destructor is a waste of CPU cycles; I recommend skipping is.

This is a lot of work (as I'm sure you can see). Using the standard C++ library can help you avoid all this work by using a suitable container - say,

```
vector<vector<unique_ptr<Robot> > > robots;
```

Now the tasks related to managing the memory for your robots will be taken care automatically.

Comment: make sure to add a  if(robots[i][j] != NULL) before deleting the individual robot

Comment: @David `delete` is null-safe.

Comment: @David One of the most beautiful things about `delete` (and also `malloc`'s counterpart `free`) is that it null-checks the value passed into it for you.

Comment: Good to know, all those years I've been wasting time doing that check

Comment: I don't like the idea of deleting individual robots. I do like the idea of having robots being taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 1):

the last line:

```
delete **robots;
```

is most likely your problem. It should be:

```
delete robots;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, but I guess i didn't specified it thoroughly, Its a requirement of the assignment that you use this triple pointer to induce a 2d array, how can I allocate\destruct it correctly?

Comment: actually I was just correcting a crash, use neil and dasblinkenlight's answers to fully correct your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
robots = new Robot**;
*robots = new Robot*[height];
```

is incorrect, you want

```
robots = new Robot**[height];
```

Comment: thanks you guys!!! I really appreciate all the quick, meticulous answers you all gave me..i can finally rap this baby up...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine why it would ever be necessary to have a `T***` and Im certainly not able to maintain resources for something like this without helper classes! If I can't use `std::vector<T>` to help with the maintenance I wiould implement a similar class (well, it is easy for me: I have implemented my own version of the C++ standard library anyway...).

I haven't looked for all problems but the immediate oroblem is that you `new robots**` and treat the result as having more than element in `robots[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

I copy my comment in this answer:

You can also use:

```
template <int WIDTH, int HEIGHT> 
class RobotsWorld
{
  public:
     /*... functions ...*/

  private:
     Robot robots[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
     /*... other private data ...*/
 };
```

And you do not have to care about `new`/`delete` stuff ;-)

However you have to implement some `operator`s to allow:

```
RobotsWorld<3,4> rw34; 
RobotsWorld<5,6> rw56 = rw34;
if (rw56 == rw34) /*...*/;
```

If you do not need to allow operations as the lines above, then `template` is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store a 2 dimension array of pointers to Robot. Here's a possible initialization routine:

```
RobotsWorld::RobotsWorld(int width,int height)
:width(width),height(height)
{
  robots = new (Robot**)[height];

  for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++){
      (*robots)[i] = new (Robot*)[width];
      for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++)
          robots[i][j] = NULL;
  }
}
```

The destructor should implement the dual operation.